# Python script to run angular test cases

Tags: javascript, python, angular

I have a requirement where I have an angular project up and running with test cases and I need to create a Python script which will all those test cases daily and will create log for it like how many passed or failed.

How to approach this?

Comment: Try to find out how you test Angular code in general, then how to automatize this using Python.

Comment: We use the 'ng test' script to test angular application, but I am not able to find the link with Python.

Comment: You read this, right? https://angular.io/guide/testing

Comment: There are more convenient ways to test an Angular app. But of course, you can spawn any process, e.g. by using [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) and check the output.

Comment: But: "One of the best ways to keep your project bug free is through a test suite, but it's easy to forget to run tests all the time. Continuous integration (CI) servers let you set up your project repository so that your tests run on every commit and pull request."